# What does "$-2\frac35$" mean?

Tags: fractions, integers

I have seen this notation before: $2\frac 3 5$. It means $2 + \frac 3 5$
I know it since $3$<sup>rd</sup> grade. It always seemed confusing to me because sometimes (especially in physics problems), $2\frac 3 5$ might mean $2 \cdot \frac 3 5$. But it math, I know it means addition. The problem is that I have never used this notation before with negative integers like in $-2\frac 3 5$. Logically, it means negative $2$ and  $3/5$, which would be $-(2 + \frac 3 5) = -2 - \frac 3 5$. However, shouldn't this be noted as $-(2\frac 3 5)$? What does $-2\frac 3 5$ really mean?

Comment: The "mixed" form is usually confusing, try to convert it to a fraction and not use the mixed form at all.

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa It's in a textbook, and I don't know how to interpret it. In general, I don't use this form.

Comment: From a basic perspective, you are correct. It should have brackets for a more formal appreciation of numbers, $-(2\frac 3 5)$. However as you have said. Since $2\frac 3 5$ means move 2 and 3/5 along a number line to the right of 0, likewise $-2\frac 3 5$ means move 2 and 3/5 along a number line to the left of 0. However if you can understand that a negative sign is simply a representation of the number $(-1)$ then it will make a lot more sense.

Comment: "But in math, I know it means addition." - this stops being true (at least in the UK) after about the age of 15. For A-levels, and universally for undergrad-and-above-level maths, you will simply not encounter mixed-form fractions.

Comment: what I meant is that if you convert it to a fraction then your question is answered, $-2\frac{3}{5}=-\frac{13}{5}$.

Comment: I think the lack of parentheses is because this form usually comes up in early age mathematics where parentheses may not be introduced

Comment: My country is not very good at anything. I encoutered this problem in a textbook for 9th graders (highschool freshman)

Comment: Classic America. Have a look at this, it's kind of college level but it defines the real numbers and seems almost obvious. https://sites.math.washington.edu/~hart/m524/realprop.pdf

Comment: I understand all your comments, but @Vinyl_coat_jawa, just to note: if paranthesis are not introduced, then negative numbers are neither.

Comment: @Tony Hellmuth, my country isn't America.

Comment: I don't know the convention for such expressions, but I would interprete is as $-(2\frac{3}{5})$

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to multiply $2$ by $3/5$ you'd have to put a multiplication sign between $2$ and $3/5$. Always. If not, you first have to calculate "the addition" and obtain $13/5$ and then put the negative sign in front of the result, thus obtaining $-13/5$, simply because that notation has priority over the minus sign in front of it.